# How to Avoide Passing Regrex Part into proxy_pass in Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to foward all request to https://myfrontend/(anything)/front/ to my backend server http://mybackend:8081 and now I setup my nginx like below:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/front/ {
  proxy_pass http://backend:8081;
}
```

However, this will pass the (.*) part to the end of the backend server like:

If I try to access: https://myfrontend/123/front/, it will be forward to http://backend:8081/123/front while what I want is to forward it to http://backend:8081 only

I've tried with rewrite and it works, but it would be a redirection while I want to keep the "123" in the URL in the browser address tab.

I've also tried the bellow configuration:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/front/ {
  proxy_pass http://backend:8081/;  #with the trailing / at the end
}
```

But it's not allowed to do so if regrex is used in the lcoation. I've tried the following configuration with static location and it works well:

```
location  /123/front/ {
  proxy_pass http://backend:8081/;
}
```

Do you have any good idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean **regex**? (not regrex )

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^ / break;` inside the same `location`.